# load html page on to UI web view iphone SDK 4.0

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to load html page on to UI web view. 
i'm developing using iphone sdk 4.0

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this method for complex User Interface in iPhone View Controller. Because we can create ".html" page easily and use this method to display complex UI

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
[webView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView release];
```